# AND in Regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I want to write a RE in which I want to find all the select statement in the init method

I have written it as follows but It is not working 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start off from something like so: `public void init\(\).*?\{.*?select\s*\*\s*from` (with the `s` flag, so that the `.` can match new line characters) example [here](https://regex101.com/r/zCVLNi/1).

The issue with your approach is that:

- Round brackets have a special meaning in regular expressions, so they need to be escaped with an extra `\`.
- By default, the period character (`.`) *does not* match a new line, so we need to add the `s` flag. In C#, this is available as `RegexOptions.SingleLine`.

P.S. If you want to make it more robust, you can use something like so: `public\s+void\s+init\s*\(\).*?\{.*?select\s*\*\s*from`. This would allow you some more freedom when it comes to having multiple spaces between keywords.